# FFT and Fast Conv on OpenCL without copying data to host

Tags: opencl, fft

I want to perform FFT, FastConv and cross-correlation on GPU and pass the results to other OpenCL kernels without copying the results to host memory.

Cannot you advice me an OpenCL implementation of FFT, FastConv and cross-correlation that can be called as kernels without transferring data from GPU to host?

Comment: From the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the OpenCL vendors (e.g., Apple, AMD, NVIDIA) have FFT samples that include kernel source. You can use these to process buffers already on the device and leave results on the device.